# I need help adjust zombie sight(aggro) range please

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have the follow range to 100, but they don't see me any further than about 30 blocks and then chase me to 100 blocks and stop. I really really need them to see me from much further (100 blocks) for a game I am making.

They will chase for 100, but not see me for 100 to follow. 
I am using 1.14 and I already know generic.followrange,Base:100.0d, but it's not letting them aggro me.
Thank you

Comment: This is probably a bug, I've heard of it before. Maybe this one: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-156039 But it's difficult to figure out exactly, because I found three open reports that all sound somewhat similar, but are also a bit vague.

Comment: I have seen that site before, but sadly nobody has replied to fixing the issue. If you were to change it in your game, would it work by chance?

Comment: Can you write the command you tried, please?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but here is the command I am using:

/summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {Attributes:[{Name:generic.followRange,Base:150.0d}]}

Comment: 11 hours – "sorry for the late reply" Allright… Well anyway, that's not how Attributes work, you need UUIDs and stuff. The wiki gives you example commands, you can adjust those using the table: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Attribute

Comment: The command on the website you linked gives me the exact same code to use.

/summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {Attributes:[{Name:"generic.followRange",Base:100.0}]} (This is copied/pasted).

I tried out the UUID with this command and sadly nothing has changed:
/summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {Attributes:[{Name:"generic.followRange",UUIDLeast:1, UUIDMost:2,Base:150.0d}]}
I also tried this one out and still no results.
/summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {Attributes:[{Name:"generic.followRange",UUIDLeast:894654, UUIDMost:2872,Base:150.0d}]}

Comment: Hm, that's weird. Then the wiki might be wrong. If you go very close to the zombie and then run away, does it keep tracking you for a long time? I think I heard about a bug similar to that once.

Comment: Yes, if I go close to it and run away say 200 blocks, it will keep following me. Since the follow range is set to 200+, it will follow me. Though, the aggro range is very short at 32 blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe thatvs due to mobs always freeze when they are 32 blocks away from players.

Comment: Oh right, that might be it. The random walking stops outside of 32 blocks. It's very easy to see by having a hundred cows nearby, then waiting for a few hours: You'll end up with a circle without cows with radius 32 blocks, because every cow inside randomly walks outside the circle at some point and then stops there.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug, I created a report for it now: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-158075

Pathfinding of mobs is apparently disabled for performance reasons when the mob is outside of a 32 block radius. So a zombie farther away will not start pathfinding towards you if it's further away, even with a higher tracking range. It will, however, continue walking towards you when you move in and out of the radius.

I don't know any good workarounds for that. It might work to teleport the zombie towards the player and quickly back again, but you would have to wait until the zombie starts walking on its own.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really do appreciate your time and effort. Especially since you reported the bug. I hope it fixes itself, I appreciate it.